# reverse proxy sub-locations

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

i would like nginx to redirect (rewrite?) all the requests for `/images`, `/css`, `/whatever` to `http://frontend/site/images` or `http://frontend/site/css`, because `http://frontend/site` is correctly mapped to `backend:port` of the site but of course it always looks for `/whatever` instead of `http://frontend/site/whatever`

is the a way to tell an nginx reverse proxy to adapt the url dinamically? without creating hundreds of `/location` directives

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `site` is static:

`rewrite ^(.*)$ /site/$1 break;`

If `site` is meant to be the hostname/domain:

`rewrite ^(.*)$ /$host$1 break;`

`rewrite` can also be used in the `server` block: [ngx_http_rewrite_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)

**Edit:**
After your comment, the answer is just reversed:

```
location /nasweb/ {
 rewrite ^/nasweb(/.*)$ $1 break;
 proxy_pass http://your-internal-nas;
}
```

This should allow you to open `https://your-external-domain.com/nasweb/` to forward your request to `http://your-internal-nas/`.

**Edit:**
To prevent wrong redirects use this:

```
proxy_redirect / /nasweb/;
```

Comment: i have an home NAS and i want to be able to reach its web-ui externally using https through a reverse proxy, avoiding ports opening, duplicate certs etc...unfortunately this NAS redirects to http ://nas/something/else/login.html. i have the proxy_pass for htt ps://public.domain/nas --> http ://nas/ but the redirect of course tries ht tps://public.domain/something/else/ which doesn't exist. What i would like to achieve is ht tps://public.domain/nas/something/else/login.html and all its related subfolders (images, css etc)... so is this still valid?

Comment: @dadoblake I've edited my answer to match the new information.

Comment: yes, this works and the first page (the login mask) loads correctly, but then most of the devices do a redirect to "/" or any other location and this breaks it all... is there any chance to catch those redirect and rewrite them to respect the proxy pass directive and go to the right device?

Comment: Added `proxy_redirect`.

Comment: ok great, the redirect got catched as expected, then the site looks for scripts into a /cmd location which is not redirected, i assume i have to specify the /cmd location (with its own proxy_pass directive) in conf file, right?

Comment: Ofcause you can always add configuration options which you need. Since I can't see/test your application I can only give some advice and direction. The rest needs to be adopted by you. Would be nice if you accept the answer if it is applicable/acceptable.